# Swift 3.0: delay of less than a second

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I'm trying to make a delay of less than a second. I found this code from the web. It doesn't however accept delays of less than a second. The Grand Dispatch Concept in Swift is a bit of a mystery to me. How should I modify this code to create a delay of 0.3 seconds?

```
    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1) //how to get 0.3 seconds here
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {        
      //code here
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that's quite easy, don't use seconds, use milliseconds:

```
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(300) // 0.3 seconds
```

Comment: Alternatively: `let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + 0.3`

Answer (score 3):

just add your reqired time to `DispatchTime.now()` and you will get a result

```
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + 0.3 //Here is 0.3 second as per your requirement 
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {        
      //code here
    }
```

Comment: Or even just `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3)`

Comment: There is nothing new in this answer, it just repeats the first including the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) { 
     // your method after delay
}
```

Remember, this will execute on main thread. If you want otherwise, check `DispatchQueue.global(qos:)` or [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue)

Answer (score -1):

use this, will work

```
let delay = 2.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) 
let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: {
     self.view_Alert.alpha = 0 
})
```